# How to change theme in Qt5 configuration editor when it is too large

Tags: 18.04, qt5

I changed theme in Qt5 configuration editor (`qt5ct` package) and now it is so big that it cannot be resized and the apply button is outside the laptop screen. How to change the theme to `gtk2` ?

Is there any command to do it?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `~/.config/qt5ct/qt5ct.conf` in a text editor.

Edit contents of the 5th line to `style=gtk2`